# React: Iterating through Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

This is the way FileObject is built  and I need help in figuring out how to iterate and find a value based on the date provided.

```
    interface MyProps{
      date: string;
      cDataFileName?: string | undefined;
      iDataFileName?: string | undefined;
    }
```

And in dev tools it shows up like this..

```
 FileObject: Array(4)
0: {date: "8/26/2020", cDataFileName: : "small_range_c-compressed.json", influenzaDataFileName: "mall_range_f-compressed.jso"}
1: {date: "8-24-2020", cDataFileName: : "small_range_c-compressed.json", iDataFileName: : "mall_range_f-compressed.jso"}
2: {date: "8-13-2020", cDataFileName: : "small_range_c-compressed.json", iDataFileName: : "mall_range_f-compressed.jso"}
3: {date: "7-15-2020", cDataFileName: : "small_range_c-compressed.json", iDataFileName: : "mall_range_f-compressed.jso"}
length: 4
```

What I need to be able to do is find if in FileObject data exists for a date of say "8/26/2020"

and get the cDataFileName and IDataFileName values for it.

```
const today = "8/26/2020";
  console.log("testing" + FileObject [today as any]);  // Its coming as testingUndefined.
  if (today in FileObject ) {
    console.log("today" + today);  // Not even going there
  }
```

Please help me figure out a best way to iterate through this array of objects to get based on the date "8/26/2020" provided.

-----------Update 1----------
This is how I had values aded to FileObject.

```
const FileObject: MyProps[] = [];

     FileObject.push({
                date: file,
                cDataFileName: MycovidFileName,
                iDataFileName: MyinDataFileName,
              });
```

Comment: FileObject.filter(x => x.date === today) if there are multiple objects with same date or .find() if only one

Comment: Thanks Ihorbond, trying that now. How can I have access to the object that matches today's date though?

Comment: I get this message TypeError: FileObject.filter is not a function.. Do I need to import any libraries for it?

Comment: It appears that FileObject is not an array then. what does console.log(Array.isArray(FileObject)) produce if you do this check right before the line that calls .filter() ?

Comment: So this statement  console.log(Array.isArray(FileObject)); is saying false and  console.log(FileObject); shows the results that I put in my post above from dev tools.. with 4 objects in it.

Comment: Could it be that it sees FileObject as type or something ? what about (FileObject as any).find(..) or [...FileObject].find(..) ? if not you might have to post complete code ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220527/discussion-between-ihorbond-and-sarah).

Comment: Yes, thank you. Give me 15 minutes please. FileObject is defined like the way I showed in the post. I will be on in another 15 minutes, do need to get this resolved today. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with typescript or react...

Just do `FileObject.find(obj => obj.date === "8/26/2020");`

Comment: Thanks Rubydessic, I get this message FileObject.find is not a function.. Do I need to import any libraries for it to work. Sorry I am learning React, JS and Typescript at the same time.

Comment: @Sarah If you're getting the error, first make sure that `FileObject` is truly an array. If it is, then you are using a really old javascript engine/browser and you may need to polyfill it. A polyfill is provided on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @RubyDescic thanks, I believe its an array of objects. I placed the code how I am pushing data to the FileObjects under update1. My browser is chrome and its all up to date. The name of file that I have all this code ends in .tsx

Comment: @Sarah If you are using the latest chrome, then what you have is not an array of objects. If you try this code with `const FileObject: MyProps[] = [];` you will see there is no problem

Comment: @Sarah You have some problem with the prototype of your 'array'. You should post how you have obtained or created this array.

Comment: @Rubydescic please check under update 1, I am showing how its declared and then how items are pushed to it. I did a console log on FileObjects and Dev tools is showing items in it which also I have shown above.

Comment: @Sarah It works perfectly fine on the TS playground so there is something missing from what you have posted. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgSwDYFMDyAjAVi4UBcMAsgJ4AKATiAA4QDaAujALwyMDcAUJwmFChQBmAQ2Api5KrQDenGPJgATYf0LQKvAOZcFMYABEVwxKgBywgLYoA-GqgawmmAB8YAVzCKUg3ikU6FBEMoY2QUcytbGHUtF3dPb19-TgBfbhN0bFwoADpqNwgACwAKWV1lVRgAIgAOAHoAJgA2RoAGBtaqgBo5BQMjDIiUQiqAFULxcHEoEBgMcUEQD0Vu3vkggbChkf5oVZSASi5ODMwcPDyCkrKFCuHq+oaAVjaO1d1+kMHLe7GJmCmMDAIFgMzmCyWnnegWCoTMPx2KD2PUOx1AkFgADdhEgWPAwmdsjkfJ5iiBsCwAHwA7A5O4sZisWqNFodN5HbjoiAgVA5JAgTTFbFIA5AA

Comment: Or perhaps something wrong with your setup that we cannot debug with the given information